# Codeigniter - trying to pass data for the user from the DB?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Following from this tutorial..
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-6-login/

I have successfully implemented and created/logged in users..

I have now added an additional input for the signup form;

**signup_form.php**

```
<?php echo form_input('sport', set_value('sport', 'sport?)')); ?>
```

In the logged in area I would like it to display the users data for 'sport'

**logged_in_area**

I like `<?php echo $this->session->userdata('sport'); ?>`

In **membership_model** I have also added
`'sport' => $this->input->post('sport'),` in `function create_member()`

The data inserts into the database correctly! :)
It is just when they are logged in it doesn't pull that user information from the 'sport' column. What have I done wrong? (I have this eerie feeling it's the echo in the logged_in_area)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add 'sport' to session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually set the value for `$this->session->userdata('sport');`

I think it is suited for you to add it with with something like

```
$this->session->set_userdata('sport', $this->input->post('sport') );
```

in

```
function create_member()
```

just after doing the insert into DB

Comment: Yeah that's correct, he forgot to add the value to the session. (loo pup the session class on the CI docs page)

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: Awesome!! Thank you so much!!! Do I have to do this with everything I want to pull from the DB for the user, during the sign up 'create_member' function? Or can I pull it in later, say, in a completely different page, in another way?

Comment: you have to do it just for the values you want to read back from session. You should be able to always read those values from DB alone also